# Postgresql substring using regex

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring, string-function

I need to run a postgresql query to get names from database but I need to sort these names alphabetically.
The names that I am gettign from database are as follows:

```
(123) Jone Lee
(22) Hans Hee
2 Dean Alloni
Alen Khan
```

I need to output to be

```
Alen Khan
2 Dean Alloni
(22) Hans Hee
(123) Jone Lee
```

I tried the following psql query:

```
select name from table order by substring(name, E'\\W+\ +(.*)');
select name from table order by substring(name, E'\\(?\\w+?\\)?\ +?(.*)');
```

My problem if the name is Alen Khan, it only return Khan, so I get:

```
Khan
Dean Alloni
Hans Hee
Jone Lee
```

Any Help would be appreciate,

kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select name 
from table 
order by substring(name, E'[a-zA-Z]+')
```

Edit as per OP's comment

```
select name
from table order by regexp_replace(name, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g')
```

Comment: This only order by the first name but I need to order by full name. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: I had to change it a bit to include the space between first and last name.

Comment: select name
from table order by regexp_replace(name, '[^a-zA-Z]\\ ', '', 'g')

Answer (score 0):

this will sort by strings last word

```
 select name from table 
 order by (string_to_array(trim(name),' '))[ array_upper(string_to_array(trim(name),' '),1)  ]
```